# How to enable kube-system/metrics-server from status "False (MissingEndpoints)"?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, metrics, azure-aks

My metrics-server was sudden not working and got below information:

```
$ kubectl get apiservices |egrep metrics
v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io kube-system/metrics-server False (MissingEndpoints)
```

I tried to implement below but still not okay:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server.git
$ cd metrics-server
$ kubectl apply -f deploy/1.8+/
```

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: try deleting metrics pods?

Comment: Hi @4c74356b41, I tried to ran `kubectl delete -f ./deploy/1.8+/` and re-ran `kubectl apply -f deploy/1.8+/` but still failed. Any commands that I can use?

Comment: are you using aks or not? if you are using aks metrics server is built-in

Comment: Yes, but it is suddenly gone but don't know how to make it work again. You may refer to [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722180/why-memory-usage-is-greater-than-what-i-set-in-kubernetess-node?answertab=active#tab-top) for what I performed before. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @4c74356b41, do you have any ideas? thanks.

Comment: it cant be gone, it would get reapplied instantly

Comment: Yes, after I upgraded kubernetes version, it is came back, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this case the solution was to upgrade kubernetes version for nodes to reapply metrics server

Answer (score 12):

I solved this issue the following:

Download metrics-server:

```
wget https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/download/v0.5.0/components.yaml
```

Remove metrics server:

```
kubectl delete -f components.yaml
```

Edit downloaded file and add *- --kubelet-insecure-tls* flag:

```
labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - --cert-dir=/tmp
    - --secure-port=443
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --kubelet-use-node-status-port
    - --metric-resolution=15s
    - --kubelet-insecure-tls
```

Create service once again:

```
kubectl apply -f components.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, upgrading to the latest (0.4.1) version of `metrics-server` probably fixes similar  issues (like `False (MissingEndpoints)`):

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/download/v0.4.1/components.yaml;
```